# Problem with retrieving data from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a problem retrieveing data from firebase database. The data structure is like this:

```
posts:{ 
    (Random key):{
       post:{
           text: "random text"
           title: "title of some kind"
           username: "username"
       }
  }
}
```

and the code I tried to retrieve text is:

```
database.ref("posts").orderByChild("post").on('value', function(snapshot){
       console.log(snapshot.val().text);
   })
```

I am new to this firebase thing, so i am sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: post is not a direct child of posts, so you cannot orderByChild() of that nested property.

Comment: okay but how can I fix it? @AlexanderStaroselsky

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code like this:

```
database.ref("posts").child(randomKey).on('value', function(snapshot){
       console.log(snapshot.child("post").child("text").val());
   })
```

Your `snapshot` is a `DataSnapshot` and it contains a `child()` method that is a `DataSnapshot` itself. To get your `text` field you just have to use `chield("text")` and get then the `val()`.

Comment: It gives me value of null

Comment: oh saw your `Random key` part. I will edit my answer

Comment: how do i define that randomKey part? I have no idea how to get that, these are automatically created by firebase on saving data

Comment: Are you trying to get every value of your text field or just a single one?

Answer (score 1):

First you can sort the result by using orderBy on any *attributes* on `post`.
For example

```
var sortedpost = firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild('post/text');
```

Or simply you can also use `orderByKey` to sort based on the document ID.

After this you can get the result you are looking for using `on` listener as below.

```
    sortedpost.on('value', function(snapshot){
       console.log(snapshot.val());
   })
```

Comment: But how can i bypass that random key part? because post is random keys child.

Comment: It will look into the nested child by itself. And why don't you add some meaningfull docID which can be done at the time of adding any data in firebase

Comment: docID is different for every post ( which should be :p) so you cannot just create a hard coded path for it, and if you want to sort the data based on the docID itself then you can use `orderBykey()`